# Why is wave energy zero at maximum deviation?

Tags: energy, waves

The equation for the energy density of a longitudinal wave in a thin rod is

$$w = \rho\cdot \left(\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial t}\right)^2$$

So the energy density seems to be 0 when the deviation ($\xi$) is maximal.

I don't understand how this can be true: if $\xi$ is big, this means that there must be big potential energy, since we have done the work of increasing $\xi$.

Comment: Hello. What is ξ? Is the deviation, that is the movement of a particle oscillating is the wave? Thanks.

Comment: Related: [In wave motion of a string both kinetic energy and potential energy are minimum at $y=y_\text{max}$ then why does the string comes down again?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208784/238167) and [Why is the potential energy of a particle in a travelling wave maximum at the mean position?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/441449/238167)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the part of the rod that is most displaced "wants" to get home, it is not because it somehow remembers its original location, but because its neighbors are pulling and pushing it back. Thus we say that the potential energy is most concentrated in those parts that are the most stretched or condensed (they pull/push the most).

The measure of stretchedness or condensedness is given by
$\left|\dfrac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}\right|$, which is up to a constant factor equal (thanks to the wave equation) to $\left|\dfrac{\partial \xi}{\partial t}\right|$. So at the points of maximum deviation ($\partial \xi/\partial x=\partial \xi/\partial t=0$) the density is average, and there's no potential energy stored there.