# Will the kinetic energy and potential energy of a wave on a string be maximum or minimum in its mean position?

Tags: waves

According to the answer key, the kinetic as well as potential energy is maximum in the mean position. I am unable to understand the reason behind this. Please explain.

Comment: The answer key is wrong. The total energy is constant, oscillating between kinetic and potential energy, just like a mass on a spring.

Comment: Very closely related: [Why is the potential energy of a particle in a travelling wave maximum at the mean position?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/441449/238167)

Comment: @Pieter: According to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/441461/238167) to the linked question, the mechanical energy of different particles on the string cannot be compared to a spring block system and it even gives some explanation for the same. The accepted answer to the question - [In wave motion of a string both kinetic energy and potential energy are minimum at $y=y_\text{max}$ then why does the string comes down again?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208784/238167) also says the same.

Comment: @GuruVishnu That accepted answer is wrong (I noted my disagreement there). It is easiest to see this with a standing wave, which is practically identical to a mass-spring system.

Comment: @Pieter: Thanks for the clarification! I think it would be better if you could post it as an answer. Comments might get deleted. Both of the accounts have been deleted and the concerned authors will not be notified.

Comment: If it's a standing wave, I agree with your perspective. But, I think the case is different with a travelling/progressive wave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mean position, the potential energy will be $0$ and all the energy will be in the form of kinetic energy. The answer key is wrong.

Comment: "The answer key is wrong."; No. It seems your answer is wrong. Please have a look at the answer to this question - [In wave motion of a string both kinetic energy and potential energy are minimum at $y=y_\text{max}$ then why does the string come down again?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208784/238167)

Comment: @GuruVishnu I have just upvoted this answer. Consider a standing wave - potential energy is zero when the string is straight. Kinetic energy is at its maximum then.

Comment: @Pieter: Yes. I agree with you. But, I think the question meant a travelling wave (not a standing wave) and the reasons stated in the linked answers also seem possible. It's also supported by a quote from the book Principles of Physics which I suppose to be a golden standard. If it's also incorrect, it would be great if you could post it as an answer to the linked question. Comments might get deleted and might be of no use to future visitors.

Comment: @GuruVishnu You are right. I have now written a dissenting answer to that accepted answer with its 11 upvotes. Thank you for spotting this.

Comment: @GuruVishnu Since the OP has not specified if the wave was standing or travelling, I assumed the former(simpler) case.

Comment: @Sam: No problem! Questions are expected to be clear. Anyway, this question will soon be closed as a duplicate of the linked (it has already 4/5 votes). If you meant a standing wave I agree with your statement. For a travelling wave you might find the linked question to be useful.